# Order of field initialization in class

Tags: java

I try to understand java scope order.

I read in book that fields and instance initializer blocks are run in the order in which they appear in
the file.

I have code bellow:

```java
public class A {
    private int x;

    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    {
        x = 1;
    }
    
    public A() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }

}
```

which compiles successfully, then I tried swap some pices of code:

```java
public class A {

    {
        x = 1;
    }

    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    private int x;


    public A() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }

}
```

and Java can't compile it in line:

```java
   System.out.println(x);
```

with `Illegal forward reference`

I don't understand why java successfully process line

```java
x = 1;
```

in second example.
BUT, it's successfully works if line with print replace by

```java
   System.out.println(this.x);
```

Comment: It's just one of those cases of "that's just the way it is".  Read all about it in the Java Language Specification at [8.3.3. Forward References During Field Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3)

Comment: Restrictions on Field References in Initializers  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3